# What Index do I need to write to prevent table-sort in a non-performant MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, join, indexing

Here is an ugly and extremely **slow** query generated by our web application. It is a custom web app that has to read off a legacy Wordpress database.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT
    p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name, p.post_excerpt, p.post_date, p.post_date_gmt, p.comment_count, post_content, post_author 
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE
    tt.taxonomy = "post_tag"
AND p.post_type = "post"
AND p.post_password = ''
AND p.post_status = "publish"
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

To give you a scope of the size of this DB:

- wp_posts has approx. 250k rows.
- wp_term_relationship has approx. 1m rows.
- wp_term_taxonomy has approx. 50k rows.
- wp_terms has approx 50k rows.

Here's the Explain statement:

```
ID| SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE   | POSSIBLE_KEYS                              | KEY              | KEY_LEN | REF                       | ROWS  | EXTRA
1 | SIMPLE      | tt    | ref    | PRIMARY,term_id_taxonomy,taxonomy          | taxonomy         | 130     | const                     | 27149 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                    | PRIMARY          | 8       | wp_mu.tt.term_id          | 1     | Using index
1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | ref    | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id                   | term_taxonomy_id | 8       | wp_mu.tt.term_taxonomy_id | 11    | Using index
1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date,optimize_slow_tax | PRIMARY          | 8       | wp_mu.tr.object_id        | 1     | Using where
```

As far as I can tell, the major issue is that MySQL is generating a temporary table AND using filesort.

From my reading thus far, if I can write the right query, we can avoid this entire debacle. If it's necessary to create a mother-huge index, I am prepared to do so.

I'm not a DBA and I don't have easy access to one, so I need help to figure out, based on this query, what I ought to write.

- Do I construct an index for all `wp_posts` columns involved in this query?
- Or just all `wp_posts` columns involved in the WHERE clause?
- Or just all `wp_posts` columns involved in the WHERE and ORDER BY clause? If so, in what order?
- Or just all `wp_posts` columns involved in the WHERE and ORDER BY, and JOIN clause? If so, in what order?
- Will re-ordering the order of the WHERE clause help in any way, or does MySQL already optimise this?
- If I were to create a MySQL View, would that help? My reading suggests no, but perhaps more recent versions of MySQL perform better these days?

Comment: MySQL Views don't help, because they are not materialized views. You are literally running the same query every time you query the view. So views are more like macros. As Rick answered, lose the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so. I guess I was hoping maybe with MySQL 8.0 coming out someone had thought to make Views more efficient, but maybe MySQL users have just been trained out of using them.

Comment: I'd love to switch to Postgresql to get materialised views, but sadly that's not my decision to make, which means it'll never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Filesort" is not as evil as it sounds.  There are other issues to fix for speed; they may eliminate the filesort.  Now for 3 tips, each of which may help significantly.

1. The many-to-many mapping for `wp_postmeta` has several inefficiencies.  Schema improvements are outlined [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).  If `wp_term_taxonomy` is many:many, but not a clone of `wp_postmeta`, then see the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).
2. Adding `INDEX(post_type, post_password, post_status, post_date)` to `p` may help significantly.  (It is hard to tell without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and knowing something about the data distribution.)  The columns can be in any order, except that `post_date` must be last.  This index *may* eliminate the 'filesort'.  But more importantly, it may get past `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` in order to honor `LIMIT`.  Without getting as far as `LIMIT`, a lot of rows must be gathered, sorted, and finally `LIMITed`.  It's the number of rows involved, *not the filesort*, that is the villain.
3. Oh, `DISTINCT` may be forcing the tmp+filesort.  That can be eliminated by doing a significant rewrite of

the query:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM posts AS p
    WHERE p....
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM .. JOIN .. JOIN ..
                       WHERE tt.taxonomy = "post_tag"
                         AND p.ID = tr.object_id )
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT ...
```

Notice how every table except `posts` has been moved into the subquery.  Previously, there was an "explode-implode" pattern -- `JOIN` explodes the number of rows involved, then `GROUP BY` (or `DISTINCT`) implodes.  This formulation avoids such.

Comment: I've tried various variations of #2 and I can't seem to get an index that adds much value.

Comment: #3 on the other hand is magic. Now I just need to figure out how to rewrite the app to rewrite the query.

Comment: I spend a lot of effort on this forum showing people how to be efficient in SQL only to find out that the 3rd party software gets in the way.  :(  The `JOIN` probably gets in the way of using the `INDEX` in #2.  Could you provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (after adding the index); maybe I can spot a way to fix it.